# How to calculate efficiency of TPS65581 Texas buck converter?

Tags: power-supply, buck, texas-instruments, efficiency

I am using Texas TPS65581 for designing buck converter  where I need to convert 12 V to 3.3 V and 1.1 V. When I go through the datasheet of IC, I can’t find the efficiency for my requirement. For example I’m using 1.1 V output with 1 A, but in datasheet they have only given graph for 1.2 V, 3.3 V and 1.5 V. Is there any formulas for the specific voltages and current, to calculate efficiency?

Link:https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65581.pdf?ts=1633951418660&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS65581
Page:13

Comment: The efficiency of the converter is dependent on the actual circuit component characteristics used inside the IC, as well as your external configuration and component choice. My suggestion is to build up/buy a demo board; configure it to your needs; then measure the input and output currents and voltages to calculate your efficiency. If you really don't want to do that; try their SPICE model configured to your needs.

Comment: Interpolate it or measure it?

Comment: Thanks, First, I need to measure it, because depending it only i have to make my power calculation.

Comment: I would interpolate from the graphs at the design stage, and then measure it after building it to get the actual number.

Comment: The graphs in the datasheet are fairly similar for 1.2 V and 1.5 V, so it's fair to consider it about the same for 1.1 V. If you need two outputs, you can consider the worst case, which will be for 1.1 V, but don't forget to account for the total current load: calculate the total power for both outputs, but consider the graphs as if you had 1.2 V with the equivalent amount of current. E.g. 3.3/0.3 + 1.1/0.91 = 2 W => ~1.2/1.67 <-- this point on the 1.2 V graph is ~72~73 %. Of course, the actual build will make the final statement.

Comment: okk, thanks a lot